# Remove modal body when submiting a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, bootstrap-modal

HTML:

```
    <div id="FinalDiv">
      <p>Completed.</p>
    </div>

<div id="modalTeste" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h2>Title</h2>
      </div>
    <div class="modal-body">Form:</div>
    <form class="radioOpcoes" id="Testemodal">

      <div class="radio">
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="selection" value="paypal"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="selection" value="money"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio disabled">
          <label><input type="radio" name="selection" value="mastercard"></label>
        </div>
    </form>

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="removeModal" name="button">Submit</button>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

JS / Jquery:

```
  let formEvents = {

    paypal: function() {
      window.open('url');
      $('#modalTeste').hide('fast')
      $('#FinalDiv').show('slow');
    },
    money: function() {
      $('#modalTeste').hide('fast')
      $('#FinalDiv').show('slow');

    },
    mastercard: function() {
      $('#modalTeste').hide('fast')
      $('#FinalDiv').show('slow');
    }
  }

  $('.radioOpcoes').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $(this).find('input:radio:checked').val();

    if (formEvents.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
      formEvents[value].call(this);
    }

  });

  $('#Testemodal').submit(function() {
    $('#modalTeste').modal('toggle');
  });
```

When I submit my form, depending on what option the user chose in the form, a div is hidden and another one is shown. However, even with that working, it's not eficient since it still has the modal active: my goal is, when submiting the form (press the submit button), every modal disappears. I can't use dismiss-modal because of the shown divs (when I use it, my "show/hide" JQuery stops working). No errors shown.

Comment: which div you want to show/hide?

Answer (score 1):

Your submit button should be inside form,

so your html will be.

```
 <div id="FinalDiv">
      <p>Completed.</p>
 </div>

<div id="modalTeste" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <form class="radioOpcoes" id="Testemodal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h2>Title</h2>
      </div>
    <div class="modal-body">Form:</div>


      <div class="radio">
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="selection" value="paypal"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="selection" value="money"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio disabled">
          <label><input type="radio" name="selection" value="mastercard"></label>
        </div>


    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="removeModal" name="button">Submit</button>

    </div>
  </form>
  </div>
```

Please let me know if your issue is fix?

Here is demo https://jsbin.com/mekifeg/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Not yet, it happens the same thing as before. The divs are hidden/shown but the fade modal stays there.

Comment: When I submit, the #modalTeste is hidden and #FinalDiv is shown.